# Placing 4 histograms in 1 plot area in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I would like to plot histograms of one variable x1, subdividing the data into 4 by values of another variable x2, and place the 4 histograms in 1 plot area, 2 histograms per row.

For example,

```
library(tidyverse)

ggplot(filter(mpg, cty < 15), aes(x = displ)) + geom_histogram(binwidth = 0.2)
ggplot(filter(mpg, cty == c(15,16,17,18)), aes(x = displ)) + geom_histogram(binwidth = 0.05)
ggplot(filter(mpg, cty == c(19,20,21,22)), aes(x = displ)) + geom_histogram(binwidth = 0.05)
ggplot(filter(mpg, cty > 23), aes(x = displ)) + geom_histogram(binwidth = 0.1)
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Better use `%in%`, i.e. `cty %in% c(15,16,17,18)`. Check `1:2 == c(0, 1, 3, 4, 5)`

Answer (score 1):

You could use `ggarrange()` from the `ggpubr`-package:

```
p1 <- ggplot(filter(mpg, cty < 15), aes(x = displ)) + 
       geom_histogram(binwidth = 0.2)
p2 <- ggplot(filter(mpg, between(cty, 15, 18)), aes(x = displ)) +
       geom_histogram(binwidth = 0.05)
p3 <- ggplot(filter(mpg, between(cty, 19, 22)), aes(x = displ)) +
       geom_histogram(binwidth = 0.05)
p4 <- ggplot(filter(mpg, cty > 23), aes(x = displ)) +
       geom_histogram(binwidth = 0.1)
ggpubr::ggarrange(p1, p2, p3, p4)
```

[image]

As was already mentioned by markus in his comment, filtering with `cty == c(15, 16, 17, 18)` is returning all the values in `mpg` where `cty` lies between 15 and 18. You should use either `cty %in% c(15, 16, 17, 18)`, `cty %in% 15:18`, or `between(cty, 15, 18)`. The last variant also works for continuous variables.